# Ball clock implemented in PHP spins out of control.

Tags: php, queue, clone, spl

I'm trying to implement the ball clock (determine how many iterations an inputed number of balls in the initial queue would go before returning to its initial order) in php. I believe at this point my code is not recognizing when to stop. I'm using an SplQueue to represent the queue and keeping an int inside each ball that represents their order.

I believe the difficulty to be in traversing the $queue in the function `hasTerminated()`. The code runs, it just doesn't stop. An input of 30, for example (`php script.php 30`) should output 30 12 hour cycles to complete, but it does not terminate. I appreciate any and all ideas as to how to access the objects of the $queue and compare them without destroying the $queue. PHP is not a language I am very comfortable with.

```
<?php
class Ball {
    static $counter = 0;
    protected $index;
    function __construct(){
        $this->index = self::$counter;
        self::$counter++;
    }
    function getIndex(){
        return $this->index;
    }
}

class Clock {
    protected $queue;
    protected $minuteTrack;
    protected $fiveMinuteTrack;
    protected $hourTrack;
    protected $count;
    protected $time = 0;

    function __construct($num){
        $this->queue = new \SplQueue;
        $this->minuteTrack = new \SplStack;
        $this->fiveMinuteTrack = new \SplStack;
        $this->hourTrack = new \SplStack;
        $this->count = $num;
        for($i = 0; $i<$num; $i++){
            $ball = new Ball();
            $this->queue->enqueue($ball); //inefficient
        }
    }

    function hasTerminated(){
        $inOrder = true;
        $prev = -1;

        $q = clone $this->queue;

        while($q->count() != 0){
            $elt = $q->dequeue();
            if($elt->getIndex() >= $prev){
                $inOrder = false;
            } else {
                $prev = $elt->getIndex();
            }
        }

        echo PHP_EOL;

        if($inOrder){
            echo 'It takes ' . $time . ' 12 hour cycles to return to the original ordering' . PHP_EOL;
            exit(0);
        } else {
            echo 'Not finished yet' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    function run(){
        while(true){
            $ball = $this->queue->dequeue();
            if(!$this->addBallToMinuteTrack($ball)){
                if(!$this->addBallToFiveMinuteTrack($ball)){
                    if(!$this->addBallToHourTrack($ball)){
                        $this->queue->enqueue($ball);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function addBallToMinuteTrack($ball){
        echo '1';
        if($this->minuteTrack->count() < 4){
            $this->minuteTrack->push($ball);
            return true;
        } else if( $this->minuteTrack->count() == 4){
            for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
                $this->queue->enqueue($this->minuteTrack->pop()); //hate this
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    function addBallToFiveMinuteTrack($ball){
        echo '5';
        if($this->fiveMinuteTrack->count() < 11){
            $this->fiveMinuteTrack->push($ball);
            return true;
        } else if( $this->fiveMinuteTrack->count() == 11){
            for($i=0; $i<11; $i++){
                $this->queue->enqueue($this->fiveMinuteTrack->pop());
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    function addBallToHourTrack($ball){
        echo '60' . PHP_EOL;
        if($this->hourTrack->count() < 11){
            $this->hourTrack->push($ball);
            return true;
        } else if( $this->hourTrack->count() == 11){
            for($i=0; $i<11; $i++){
                $this->queue->enqueue($this->hourTrack->pop()); //hate this
            }
            $this->time = $this->time + 1; //In half day increments
            $this->hasTerminated();

            return false;
        }
    }
}

foreach (array_slice($argv, 1) as $arg) {
    if(!is_numeric($arg)){
        echo 'Arguments must be numeric' . PHP_EOL;
        exit(1);
    } else {
        $clock = new Clock($arg);
        $clock->run();
    }
}
?>
```